# Self signed certificate for Adobe Air application

Tags: apache-flex, air, certificate

I nedd to create a self signed certificate for my desktop app. What do I need to enter in these fields?

- Organization unit
- Organization name

Does *Organization* means my agency's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Flextras pointed out these are optional on self-signed certificates. When purchasing a certificate from a certificate authority like [thawte](http://www.thawte.com/) or [verisign](http://www.verisign.com/) they are used to verify the existence of your company. In this case

- **Organization Name** is the legal name of your business
- **Organization Unit** is the specific branch within your business

[This PDF](http://www.thawte.com/assets/documents/guides/pdf/enroll_codesign_eng.pdf) from thawte touches on it and [this article](http://www.digicert.com/csr-creation.htm) explains it more explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

For Organization Name I put my company's formal legal name; DotComIt.  For Organization Unit I think I either left it blank.

If memory serves me neither of them are required; so you can leave them both blank.